# custom validation methods for forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

My problem is that my error messages never print and I don't think validate is happening. I am have never done validations before and am trying to learn how to do this.

Controller:

```
def create
    @requests = Request.new(request_params)

    if @requests.save
      redirect_to root_path
      flash[:success] = "Your request has been submitted for approval"
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end
```

Request model

```
class Request < ApplicationRecord

validate :borrow_date_bigger_than_current_date, on: :create

def borrow_date_bigger_than_current_date
    if (:borrow_date.to_s < Date.today.to_s)
        errors.add(:borrow_date, "Checkout date cannot be earlier than the current date") 
    end
end
```

and a form that goes like this

```
form_for @requests do |request|
<% if @requests.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@requests.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this message from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
      <% @requests.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li>
          <%= msg %>
        </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>
 ... form stuff below here ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to do this:

```
if (:borrow_date.to_s < Date.today.to_s)
```

You're comparing two `Strings`, not two `Dates`.

Comment: I am using a date_field for borrow_date. I get this error "comparison of Symbol with Date failed" if I try to compare it without making it a string. I actually have another place where we compare a bunch of cases with dates and we convert those to strings and it seems to work fine. I still think the method is not executing though I may be wrong. Thank you for your reply

Comment: Sure thing. By the way, you could always just go bare knuckles on it and put a 'put' statement in the validation and see what happens in console. Then you'd know if it was being called.

Comment: just gave that a try. The method is not executing.